C++ call member function pointer from friend class
class classA {
public:
    classA() { 
        if (condition) { cp = &classA::Add; }
        else { cp = &classA::Mul; }
    }
private:
    typedef int (classA::*ComputeMethod)(int x, int y);
    int Add(int x, int y) { return x+y; }
    int Mul(int x, int y) { return x*y; }
    ComputeMethod cp;
    friend class classB;
};

class classB {
public:
   void Compute(int x, int y) { (a.*cp)(x,y); } // why this does not compile?
private:
    classA a;
};

As in the code above, why Compute method in classB not compile? the compiler says "Indirection requires pointer operand "ComputeMethod" invalid".
please help me.

Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the full and complete build log.

What is condition?  A [mcve] would be helpful.

(a.*a.cp)(x,y)

@RetiredNinja thank you! it works. But ...... it's weird.

@Ray It's not weird. To call a "pointer to member", you need the pointer which is a.cp -- and you need an object to call it on, which is the a.*<pointer> part... it just looks funny because the source of the pointer and the object to apply it on are the same, which is somewhat unusual. You could just write it as auto pointer=a.cp; (a.*pointer)(x,y); if that makes it clearer...

@ChristianStieber Yes! crystal clear. Now I understand why the syntax is like this.

The Compute function needs to have a type (or be void) or else it doesn't matter what you put in the function. I also don't see a good reason for having the Compute function in classB instead of in classA.

@TedLyngmo it rather annoys me that we can do typedef int (ComputeMethod)(int, int); globally and then ComputeMethod Add; in class to declare class member... but its type is  int (Class::*ComputeMethod)(int, int) and we cannot use that to define a method in any relevant way, only in traditional. It's a mixture of various lefovers from C.

typedef int (classA::*ComputeMethod)(int x, int y); looks odd and might be unportable  - no need for formal argument names, some compilers do not accept that. Modern way to write this is using ComputeMethod = int (classA::*)(int,int).

@Swift-FridayPie It was the classB::Compute member function I was thinking of. It should most probably be int but right now it doesn't have any return type, which makes it invalid for that reason alone.

@TedLyngmo It felt like it was original constructor (classB being Compute). well, yeah, constructors cannot be pointed at for this reason (or called directly in any way, because an id-expression requires a pointer). At this point we might want a function object, operator() can have its addres be taken

@Swift-FridayPie If it had been a constructor, I guess it'd be ok as-is but it's not. :) In OPs setup I also wonder why Add and Mul are non-static member functions at all. They are not using any value from any member variable so there's really no need. One could just make an array of lambdas instead.  example

Instead of weird I'd say uncommon. There are a lot of things in C++ grammar, especially new things getting shoehorned in, that are odd the first time you see them but perfectly normal once you use them a bit. The first time I saw iostreams, structured binding, and lambdas I was totally confused but now they are commonplace and make perfect sense. shrug Member function pointers will probably always be a little strange to me just because I really don't use them, there are alternatives I prefer, but still a good thing to understand when you see it.

The confusing thing is (I think) that x.*y looks a lot like x.y, but unlike it, x and y are independent expressions. x must evaluate to an object and y (without considering x at all) to a pointer-to-member in the type of x. If you think of it as a function call dereference(x, y), it makes (slightly) more sense.

@Ray Please also read this.

@TheNomad thank you, that should be the best practice.

@TedLyngmo and Swift-FridayPie  sorry I forgot the void, it should be void Compute()..., this is just a hand written minimal demo of my real code, not been compiled. The real code is much more complicated, classA has many member objects being used in Add() and Mul().


it works. But ...... it's weird

You can make it more readable by using std::invoke with c++17:
std::invoke(a.cp, a, x,y); //compiles 


The old syntax(without std::invoke) to do this would be:
----vvvv------------>member function pointer 
(a.*a.cp)(x,y);
-^------------------>object

